# Cache error with two WFE servers

Tags: sharepoint

We have two WFE servers pointing to a content database. We have updated a .js file from one WFE which appears fine however from the other WFE server, the JS file hasn't updated, even though they are pointed to the same content database.

I have tried clearing the cache from both servers and still having the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your wsp deployment and see if its successfully deployed on both WFEs probably it looks like deployment on both servers was not success